# Adding elements in a column based on unique elements of another column

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, rows, columnsorting

I have a matrix called as `single_matrix_with_time_id`, the first column corresponding to `frame_number`, second column corresponding to `time`, third column with `identity`, fourth column with `error`, fifth and sixth column with `X and Y coordinates` and seventh column with `Camera_id`.

What i am trying to do is to take the unique elements from the second column (`time`) and the elements corresponding to the unique elements of `time` from the `first and seventh column` and add it to first, second and third column of a new matrix called `final_plot_matrix`. I tried to do this in the code shown below, But it is not giving me the expected outcome. Code and image of the `single_matrix_with_time_id` is attached. Any help will be appreciated.

```
final_plot_matrix = nan(length(unique(single_matrix_with_time_id(:,2)))+1,length(final_filtered_ant_id)+3);
final_plot_matrix(1,4:length(final_filtered_ant_id)+3) = 
final_filtered_ant_id;
final_plot_matrix = repelem(final_plot_matrix,1,2);
final_plot_matrix(:,1) = [];
final_plot_matrix(:,2) = [];
final_plot_matrix(:,3) = [];
final_plot_matrix(2:length(unique(single_matrix_with_time_id(:,2)))+1,3) = unique(single_matrix_with_time_id(:,2));
[C,ia,ic] = unique(single_matrix_with_time_id(:,2));
frame_number = ia(single_matrix_with_time_id(:,1));
Camera_id = ia(single_matrix_with_time_id(:,3))
final_plot_matrix(2:length(unique(single_matrix_with_time_id(:,2)))+1,2) = frame_number
final_plot_matrix(2:length(unique(single_matrix_with_time_id(:,2)))+1,1) = Camera_id
```

[image: single_matrix_witj_time_id]

Comment: i think you should find indexes of each unique column the use intersection to merge all indexes

Comment: @user3452134 didnot understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were on the right track using "unique", but it should be more simple than that. Call unique on the time data (second column) to get the unique row numbers. Unique returns unique values as the first output, and the indices as the second. We only care about the indices, so ignore the first output.

```
[~, ia] = unique(single_matrix_with_time_id(:,2);
```

Now you know the row and column numbers you want from the original data. Row numbers are in "ia", and you want columns 1, 2, and 7. So make a new matrix:

```
final_plot_matrix = single_matrix_with_time_id(ia,[1 2 7]);
```

That's it! If you wanted to switch the order of the columns (for example, to make time the first column instead of second), just switch the order of the columns in the line above. For example:

```
final_plot_matrix = single_matrix_with_time_id(ia,[2 1 7]);
```